# Git add -e without requiring arithmetic logic on hunk headers

Tags: git, version-control, staging, git-add

I have made a few changes to a branch on my git repository. However, I would like to add/stage those changes in batches of different commits.

For this, I usually add files with the `-e` or `-p` flag to include only the bits I want.

Unfortunately, this usually takes ages since I have to keep counting the lines added and removed so I can update the hunk header i.e `@@ -32,7 +32,7 @@`.

I have found out that `git apply` has a flag called `--recount` which basically ignore hunk headers and do the math based on the diff however I am not sure if `git apply` will just stage the files or replace the files content with the diff.

Anyway, I would like to know if there is any less painful way to perform `git add -e` without having to recalculate all hunk headers while staging only smaller bits of the file?

I was looking for a native way to do that within git itself without having to use a GUI application, if that is at all possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been my experience that `git add --patch` aka `git add -p` handles this very well. I've never had to do arithmetic on line numbers, just nav through the hunks and apply what I want.  Sometimes I have to split some. Anything more than a spelling error I apply just the good ones and bounce out to vim to correct the larger goofs.  One stunt that might help is to add a marker to the hunks you fix this way, a pack of @'s or something, then you can / to them, e them, y them and be done with it. Yay for edit macros.